# Disable ctrl+alt+f in X runtime

Tags: linux, x11

How do I disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f*</kbd> shortcut that switches me between terminals? I would like to do that one time as I have an application that uses such shortcuts internally in Linux.  I want to avoid restarting X.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line to `xorg.conf`:

```
Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
```

It should be located in the section `ServerFlags`
`xorg.conf` can be found at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` most of the time.